# YII 1.1 main.php PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, yii

Приветствую!

Получил проект на php YII Фреймворке.
Настроил IIS запускаю проект.
В файле protected/config/main.php

Такая конструкция:

```
 <?php
   return CMap::mergeArray(
   //подключаем файл из общего пакета с глобальными настройками
   (require YIICOMPACK_DIR . '/config/main.php'),
   //файл проекта с настройками проекта
   (require PROJECT_DIR . '/protected/config/project.php'),
   //локальный неверсионизированный файл настроек, определяет дополнительные настройки на локальной машине
   (file_exists(PROJECT_DIR . '/protected/config/local.php') ? require(PROJECT_DIR . '/protected/config/local.php') : array())
 );
```

При запуске получаю вот такое:

```
PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant YIICOMPACK_DIR - assumed 'YIICOMPACK_DIR' in C:\inetpub\portal\demos\hangman\protected\config\main.php on line 4 PHP Warning: require(YIICOMPACK_DIR/config/main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\portal\demos\hangman\protected\config\main.php on line 4 PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'YIICOMPACK_DIR/config/main.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\portal\demos\hangman\protected\config\main.php on line 4
```

Где должны быть задекларированы эти переменные?

Пробовал заменять на `(dirname(__FILE__). 'путь')` - получаю таймаут. Увеличивал с 30 до 60 и до 100 результат один.

**Обновление**

Определил в index.php

```
define('YIICOMPACK_DIR', 'C://inetpub/portal/demos/hangman/protected/');
define('PROJECT_DIR', 'C://inetpub/portal/demos/hangman/');
```

При запуске тот же таймаут или нехватка памяти

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1920991232 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1792 bytes) in > C:\inetpub\portal\demos\hangman\protected\config\main.php on line 4.

При увеличении памяти, получаю таймаут. При увеличении таймаута, большую нехватку памяти.

Comment: Могу предположить, что константы должны быть объявлены в index.php. А эта конструкция представляет собой - сбор конфига проекта по частям - CMap::mergeArray - это допиленный array_merge.

Comment: вы мне объясните, с чего вы взяли что `define('YIICOMPACK_DIR', 'C://inetpub/portal/demos/hangman/protected/');`. Вы сейчас зацикливаете скрипт, в файле подключаете сам файл, естественно не увлечения памяти, не таймаута не поможет.

Comment: Предположил, раз в config/main.php есть строка  `(require YIICOMPACK_DIR . '/config/main.php')`, то переменная должна включать в себя путь от корня до **protected** проекта, чтобы путь в принципе был существующим. В структуре проектов на YII **config/main.php** как я понял, лежит только там.

Answer (score 1):

К Yii эти константы никакого отношения не имеют. В комментариях в коде четко прописано что делается и зачем. Соответственно вам нужно найти оба файла

> файл из общего пакета с глобальными настройками
>
> файл проекта с настройками проекта

Если проект разворачивали из гит репозитория, посмотрите файл `.gitignore` может поможет в нахождении конфигов.